# Unobtrusive javascript not working with AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am facing very strange thing with `AJAX` and `Unobtrusive JavaScript` that I have two pages

- ajaxcontent.php
- index.php

index.php has

```
<div id="cont"></div>
<input type="button" id="a" value="load plz.">

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('a').onclick = function  () {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            ari = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            ari = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }

        ari.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ari.readyState == 4 && ari.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = ari.responseText;

            }
        }

        ari.open("GET","button.php",true);
        ari.send();
    }
    document.getElementById('b').onclick = function  () {
        alert('a');
    }
</script>
```

And ajaxcontent.php has only

```
<input type="button" id="b"/>
```

and the problem is unobtrusive Javascript is not working.
After laoding of ajaxcontent when i click on button it doesn't show alert pop up. 
i have tried that i added

```
document.getElementById('b').onclick = function  () {
    alert('a');
}
```

this code on ajaxcontent.php but it still not working.
THe only way to make it work that i have to add inline javascript as

```
<input type="button" id="b" onclick="hi();"/>
```

and replace this function with

```
document.getElementById('b').onclick = function  () {
    alert('a');
}
```

with

```
function hi() {
    alert('a');
}
```

so please help me that how to use unobtrusive js here and please don't give jQuery based answer thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `document.getElementById('b')` can only find an element that is in the DOM at the time you call this function.

Because the element with the id `b` is in the data you request in the click event, the function will not find any element. You most likely should have seen an error in the console like `cannot set property onclick of undefined`.

AJAX requests are async by default (and you should not make them sync because this will block the window of the browser).

So you need to place the `document.getElementById('b').onclick = ...` in the `onreadystatechange` check right after the `document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = ari.responseText;`

Here a simple example how to generalize your request:

```
function doAjaxRequest(url, complete, error) {
  var ari; //<<<< you should define your variables using var otherwise it is set in the global scope
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ari = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    ari = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }

  ari.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ari.readyState === 4) {

      if (ari.status === 200) {
        // if complete callback is passed, then call it if request was successful
        if (typeof complete === 'function') {
          complete(ari.responseText);
        }
      } else {
        // if error callback is passed then call it if request was not successful
        if (typeof error === 'function') {
          error(ari.status, ari.statusText);
        }
      }

    }
  }

  ari.open('GET', url, true);
  ari.send(null);
}

document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() {
  doAjaxRequest('button.php', function( data ) {

    document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = data;

    document.getElementById('b').onclick = function() {
      alert('a');
    }

  }, function(errorCode, errorMessage) {
    //do something on error
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks :) i got it your answer is clear and brief :)

Comment: can you give me some other methods than this?? plz

Comment: @Null What do you mean with _other methods_ ? For attaching the event listener, for handling AJAX?

Comment: handling AJAX ! as i dont want to put code after ...responseText but still want to use unobtrusive JavaScript?

Comment: @Null you need to put it after `responseText` otherwise `document.getElementById('a')` would not find the element. Another solution would be to listen to the `click` on e.g. `body` and catch the `click`event in the bubbling phase and check if the source of the event has the id `a` and handle your event there (this is called delegating). But you can generalize the way you request our data so that you can reuse it. I added an example to my answer (the example should be work, but i need to mention that I had no time to test it)

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event attaches to elements currently in the DOM when the function is triggered. Because the button in ajaxcontent.php is added to the DOM after the function was called, no event is attached.

To rectify this, you can add a snippet inside ari.onreadystatechange to detatch events then attach the event again.

```
ari.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ari.readyState == 4 && ari.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = ari.responseText;
            // remove events
            document.getElementById('b').onclick = null;
            // attach events 
            document.getElementById('b').onclick = function() {
                   alert('a');
            }
        }
    }
```

It's important to remove events because it may (although i was using jQuery when i learnt by mistake) cause double execution.

If you add javascript code inside ajaxcontent.php, that code will not be executed unless you extend your ari.onreadystatechange function to scan for javascript and execute it. The way I do this, is I put my javascript in AJAX requested pages in a input with class 'ajax-js' and scan for those input boxes and execute the code one by one, removing the class as I go.

Comment: `document.getElementById('b').onclick = null` does not remove callbacks registered by jQuery, because jQuery uses `addEventListener`/`removeEventListener` which is fortunately not affected by code using the old way of attaching event listeners. You only need to use `.onclick = null;`  if you want to remove a callback you added with `.onclick = callback;` before. If you want to replace such a callback it is sufficient to just write `.onclick = callback;` you don't need to remove it first.

Comment: @t.niese when I mentioned jQuery I was referring to when I tested a while ago using the .on('click', function) handler. The principle applies to all handlers. (edit: assuming of course the same listener is used)

Comment: `.on('click', function)` internally uses `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`(for older IE), so `.onclick = null;` has not effect to callbacks  attached with `.on('click', function)`. Because of that and because `.on[event] = function` can always hold only one callback function you can remove the line `document.getElementById('b').onclick = null;` in your sample code, because it has no effect, as you overwrite it right at the next line.

Comment: You misunderstand, **I did not combine** jQuery's `.on(event, function)` with vanilla `onclick = null;`. I simply mentioned jQuery for full discretion of what I was using when double execution last occurred for me, merely a couple of weeks ago. I felt the need to mention it, because it is an issue which is **library agnostic**.

Comment: I just want to make clear that it is misleading how you wrote that :). In the case of using `element.on[event]` it is **not** important to remove a previously added event listener added with `element.on[event]` before, when you add a new one with `element.on[event]`, because the old one is just overwritten. And someone could think `element.on[event]=null;` removes all because of the `// remove events` which is not the case. For `addEventListener` or `$(element).on(event, ...)` it is - like you said - important to keep track if a callback was already added to prevent double attaching/execution.